# What JavaScript datatable is similar to Google spreadsheets?

Tags: javascript, datatable

I'm looking for a JavaScript datatable that has similar features to [Google spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/) or Microsoft Excel.

Datatables such as [Datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) and [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/) are more for displaying  tabular data than inline editing in the same style as Excel.

[YUI3 has a datatable](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/) that looks promising but unfinished.

[YUI2 has a datatable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) that also close, but its style of inline editing is more "click cell, edit text, click save button" style.

Answer (score 2):

[handsontable](http://handsontable.com/)

a minimalistic Excel-like data grid editor for HTML, JavaScript & jQuery